# Knowing the type of output signal

Tags: signal, photodiode, photoresistor

I have a [digital photocell](http://www.theben.de/en/Products/Accessories/Others/Digital-flush-mounted-light-sensor), where after dissembling, I see that it uses a ATMEGA88 chip([datasheet of the chip](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2545.pdf)), but I do not have the schematic of the photocell.

The whole photocell has only a pair of +/- signal output wires, nothing else, no power input cable. Is it possible to guess the type of signal that are coming out of the wires? like it's a pair of Tx, Rx, 8-bit signal? Or it's a scl/sda signal?

And how about operating voltages? I see from the datasheet that the chip operates at 1.8 - 5.5V. Could power be supplied with the signal on the same wire?

EDIT:
Photos of the board in the photocell:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If it has got only 2 wires and a μC inside (which needs power), then I would guess that this is a [4-20 mA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_loop) output.  It could be digital or analog.  The same pair of wires powers the sensor and carries the signal as varying current.

It's strange that the manufacturer's datasheet doesn't specify the output.  You could  contact them and ask for more information.

If you post a photo of the PCB inside the sensor, may be we can discern more.

Comment: Please see the edited question, photos are as posted, thanks!